# How to make the main thread finish last

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a parser that works with the help of Executor.newCachedThreadPool(), and faced the fact that the main thread in which the record to the JSON file is written is executed before the child ones. As a result, we have an empty file...
I know the topic of multithreading rather poorly and can not understand ge wrong. I tried to use the Join () method on the main thread, but in the end the program just hangs up when approaching this part

**Main.java**

```
import model.Product;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String rootUrl = "example.com";
        System.out.println("Started parsing: " + rootUrl);
        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();

        HtmlParser htmlParser = new HtmlParser();
        List<Product> productList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        htmlParser.parse(rootUrl, productList);

        Printer.printToJson(productList);

        System.out.println("Finish: completed in " + ((double) System.currentTimeMillis() - m) / 1000 + " seconds");
    }
}
```

**HtmlParser.java**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import ua.bala.model.Product;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class HtmlParser {

    private static AtomicInteger httpRequestsCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static AtomicInteger getHttpRequestsCounter() {
        return httpRequestsCounter;
    }

    public void parse(String url, List<Product> productList) {
        try {
            Document page = getPage(url);
            parsePage(page, productList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Document getPage(String url) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        httpRequestsCounter.getAndIncrement();
        return document;
    }

    private void parsePage(Document page, List<Product> productList) {
        Elements productElements = page.select("a.dgBQdu");

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (Element element: productElements){
            service.execute(() -> {

                Long articleID = Long.parseLong(element.attr("id"));
                String name = "NAME";
                String brand = "BRAND";
                BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
                Set<String> colors = new HashSet<>();
                String url = "https://www.aboutyou.de" + element.attr("href");
                Document innerPage;

                try {
                    innerPage = getPage(url);
                    Element innerElement = innerPage.selectFirst("[data-test-id='BuyBox']");
                    name = innerElement.selectFirst("div.dZjUXd").text();
                    brand = innerElement.selectFirst("[data-test-id='BrandLogo']").attr("alt");
                    colors = new HashSet<>(innerElement.select("span.jlvxcb-1").eachText());
                    String priceStr = innerElement.selectFirst("div.dWWxvw > span").text().replace("ab ","").replace(" EUR","").replace(",", ".");
                    price = new BigDecimal(priceStr);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Product product = new Product(articleID, name, brand, colors, price, url);
                addProduct(product, productList);
            });
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }

    private synchronized void addProduct(Product product, List<Product> productList){
        System.out.println("Product " + product.getID() + " parsed");
        System.out.print(product);
        productList.add(product);
        System.out.printf("Product %d added to list\n%n", product.getID());
    }
}
```

**Printer.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import model.Product;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Printer {

    private static final String path = "";
    private static final String fileName = "productsOutput";

    public static void printToJson(List<Product> products){

        products.sort(Comparator.comparing(Product::getID));

        System.out.println("Product list start printing to JSON");
        try (final Writer writer = new FileWriter(path + fileName + ".json")) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            gson.toJson(products, writer);
            System.out.println("Product list printed to JSON");
            System.out.printf("Amount of triggered HTTP requests: %s%nAmount of extracted products: %s%n",
                                 HtmlParser.getHttpRequestsCounter(), products.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Printer.java**

```
package model;

import lombok.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {

    private static AtomicLong productsCounter = new AtomicLong(1);

    private Long ID;
    private Long articleID;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Set<String> colors;
    private String url;

    {
        ID = productsCounter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public Product(Long articleID, String name, String brand, Set<String> colors, BigDecimal price, String url) {
        this.articleID = articleID;
        this.name = name;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.price = price;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public static AtomicLong getProductsCounter() {
        return productsCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", ID, articleID, name, brand, price, colors, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'As a result ...': no it isn't. The JVM won't exit until all non-daemon threads have exited. You may have an empty file but not for this reason. It is because you are printing the result before the computation is finished. Print it in the computation thread, not in `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to overcome this. Using observables, or blocking main thread or using an interface without blocking the main thread. For me, interface would be a good choice. If you are familiar with java interface, you can implement an interface in order to print recent parsed products. Here is how step by step:

Interface class:

```java
public interface ProductsListener {
    void onProductsReady(List<Product> products);
}
```

MainImpl class (NOT Main class itself):

```java
public class MainImpl implements ProductListener {
    // When product list loading is done this func will be called
    void onProductsRead(List<Product> products) {
        Printer.printToJson(productList);
    }
}
```

In Main class:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MainImpl listener = new MainImpl();
        htmlParser.setProductListener(listener);
        // Rest of the code...
    }
}
```

In HtmlParser class:

```java
public class HtmlParser {
    private MainImpl productListener;
    //...

    public void setProductListener(MainImpl listener) {
        // Alternatively you can do it in a constructor
        productListener = listener;
    }
    //...

    private void parsePage(Document page, List<Product> productList) {
        Elements productElements = page.select("a.dgBQdu");
        int parseCount = 0;

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (Element element: productElements){
            service.execute(() -> {

                Long articleID = Long.parseLong(element.attr("id"));
                String name = "NAME";
                String brand = "BRAND";
                BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
                Set<String> colors = new HashSet<>();
                String url = "https://www.aboutyou.de" + element.attr("href");
                Document innerPage;

                try {
                    innerPage = getPage(url);
                    Element innerElement = innerPage.selectFirst("[data-test-id='BuyBox']");
                    name = innerElement.selectFirst("div.dZjUXd").text();
                    brand = innerElement.selectFirst("[data-test-id='BrandLogo']").attr("alt");
                    colors = new HashSet<>(innerElement.select("span.jlvxcb-1").eachText());
                    String priceStr = innerElement.selectFirst("div.dWWxvw > span").text().replace("ab ","").replace(" EUR","").replace(",", ".");
                    price = new BigDecimal(priceStr);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Product product = new Product(articleID, name, brand, colors, price, url);
                addProduct(product, productList);
                parseCount++; // Count each element that has been parsed
                // Check if all elements have been parsed
                if(parseCount >= productElements.size()) {
                    // All products are done, notify the listener class
                    productListener.onProductsReady(productList);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Not tested, but the interface logic must work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the main thread to wait for the worker threads to finish would be to have `HTMLParser` return its `ExecutorService` so that `Main.main` can call `awaitTermination(...)` on it.

Or ... if you didn't want to expose the service to the `Main` class, you could add a "wait until it is done" method to the `HTMLParser` classes API.

---

Note: it is probably a bad idea for each call to `parsePage` to create and then tear down its own thread pool executor service.  You should probably create one thread pool for each `HTMLParser` instance, and reuse it in each `parsePage` call.

In addition, doing this will make solving your problem with `main` easier.